# Como exibir um alert do controller asp.net mvc

Tags: asp.net-mvc

Como exibir um `alert` ou um `Response.Write` do `controller`, em tela, para saber se está passando por ele ?

Comment: Em tela ou em console?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Em tela, tipo, to fazendo uma alteração e não está aparecendo, ai queria saber se está passando por esse controller com um alert ou um response.write.

Comment: A maneira certa de fazer isso é colocando *breakpoints* no *Controller*, não lançando `Response.Write`. Isso é extremamente tosco de se fazer.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez Puts então, o ruim é que estou dentro do iis e esse projeto está uma bagunça, tem partes mvc e partes em asp classico. Ai deu um problema e sobrou pra mim. rs. To mexendo pelo notepad++ .. :(

Comment: Você não consegue nem debugar sua aplicação, é isto?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, isso. Estou tendo que mexer dentro do IIS.

Comment: Não precisa toda essa volta. Você pode criar um projeto formato *Web Site* dentro do Visual Studio importando o diretório do IIS pra dentro dele e debugar ele por lá.

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez, mesmo ele todo bagunçado e com partes em asp classico ?

Comment: Ué, qual o problema?

Comment: @CiganoMorrisonMendez pensei que não funcionaria asp classico no vs.

Comment: Faça um teste ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode retornar um alerta:

```
return JavaScript("<script>alert(\"método CarregarGrid()\")</script>");
```

Comment: Mais dessa forma ira abrir uma página em branco conteúdo do script, como seria para exibir a caixa de mensagem?